# Errors while scaffolding identity into .net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, .net-5

I have a MVC application with existing authorization. Everything works well, but following the documentation for scaffolding identity I get the following error:

> ~/obj/Debug/net5.0/Razor/Templates/Identity/Pages/_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml.g.cs(36,135):
> error CS0103: The name 'StartTagHelperWritingScope' does not exist in
> the current context

This error repeats for 'EndTagHelperWritingScope' and 'CreateTagHelper'
Target Framework is .NET 5.0 and my package references 5.0.1, on Ubuntu 20.04LTS machine.

Please assist. I can't find this error anywhere on web search.
My Templates/Identity/Pages/_ViewImports.cshtml:

> @inherits Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating.RazorTemplateBase
> @@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
> @@using @(Model.Namespace).Areas.Identity
> @@using @(Model.Namespace).Areas.Identity.Pages
> @@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
> @{
> if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.UserClassNamespace) && Model.UserClassNamespace != "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity")
> {
> @:@@using @(Model.UserClassNamespace)
> }
> }

I have also added custom user fields by extending the IdentityUser class with a class called ApplicationUser.

Comment: Does your project have  Dependencies > Microsoft.AspNetCore.App > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor?  Could also try deleting obj folder under your project from your file system and try rebuilding project, then try adding Identity scaffolding again.

Comment: Yes those dependencies are present. I have removed the obj folder, build fails with the same error.

Comment: OK.  Can you post your _ViewImports.cshtml file.  It should have a line:
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

Comment: Please see my edited post